# Objects binding in Spring MVC form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm working on a test application using Spring MVC.
I have a `Person` class and a `Group` class. Every `Person` object references a `Group` object.

Now I implemented a jsp that show Person data and allow editing. Inside my form i put a select control to select the pearson's group:

```
<sf:select path="group">
    <sf:options items="${groupList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
</sf:select>
```

It shows the correct group when I load the page, but I cannot save changes, because in the controller I get only the string representing the group **id**.

So, my question is: how can I obtain a `Group` object instead of its id in my controller?

**UPDATE**
Here my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details", params = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,
        BindingResult result) {
    this.personManager.savePerson(p);
    return "redirect:/people/details?id=" + p.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own GroupEditor (that will populate the group object instance correcty) by extending PropertyEditorSupport. Then bind that in your controller :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)     {
      binder.registerCustomEditor(Group.class, new GroupEditor(groupService));
}
```

and your actual editor could look somethign like this :

```
public class GroupEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    private final GroupService groupService;

    public GroupEditor(GroupService groupService){
        this.groupService= groupService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      Group group = groupService.getById(Integer.parseInt(text));
      setValue(group);
    }
}
```

[Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration)

Comment: What do I have to change in my method signature? Do I have to change this way 
`public String save(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p, Group g, BindingResult result)` ?

Comment: Nothing if its the same as your original question. The binding result is only necessary if you are validating it ...